# How to create increment folder name in php

Tags: php, html

I have an HTML form with three inputs:

- name
- consultant id (number)
- picture upload

After the user submits the form, a php script would:

- Create folder with the submitted name
- Inside the folder create a txt file with: name + consultant id (given number)
- Inside the folder, store the image uploaded by user

The most important thing I want is that folders created by the php file should be increased by 1. What I mean: folder1 (txt file + image), folder2 (txt file + image), folder3 (txtfile + image) and so on...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different methods for accomplishing what you describe. One option would be look at all existing folders(directories) when you attempt to create a new one and determine the next highest number.

You can accomplish this by using [`scandir`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) on your parent output directory to find existing files.

Example:

```php
$max=0;
$files=scandir("/path/to/your/output-directory");
$matches=[];
foreach($files as $file){
    if(preg_match("/folder(\d+)/", $file, $matches){
        $number=intval($matches[1]);
        if($number>$max)
            $max=$number;
    }
}
$newNumber=$max+1;
```

That is a simple example to get you the next number. There are many other factors to consider. For instance, what happens if two users submit the form concurrently? You would need some synchronization metaphor(such as semaphore or file lock) to ensure only insert can occur at a time.

You could use a separate lock file to store the current number and function as a synchronization method.

I would highly encourage finding a different way to store the data. Using a database to store this data may be a better option.

If you need to store the files on disk, locally, you may consider other options for generating the directory name. You could use a timestamp, a hash of the data, or a combination thereof, for instance. You may also be able to get by with something like [`uniqid`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid). Any filesystem option will require some form of synchronization to address race conditions.

Here is a more complete example for sequentially creating directories using a lock file for the sequence and synchronization. This omits some error handling that should be added for production code, but should provide the core functionality.

```
define("LOCK_FILE", "/some/file/path"); //A file for synchronization and to store the counter
define("OUTPUT_DIRECTORY", "/some/directory"); //The directory where you want to write your folders

//Open the lock file
$file=fopen(LOCK_FILE, "r+");
if(flock($file, LOCK_EX)){
    //Read the current value of the file, if empty, default to 0
    $last=fgets($file);
    if(empty($last))
        $last=0;
    //Increment to get the current ID
    $current=$last+1;
    //Write over the existing value(a larger number will always completely overwrite a smaller number written from the same position)
    rewind($file);
    fwrite($file, (string)$current);
    fflush($file);
    //Determine the path for the next directory
    $dir=OUTPUT_DIRECTORY."/folder$current";
    if(file_exists($dir))
        die("Directory $dir already exists. Lock may have been reset");
    //Create the next directory
    mkdir($dir);
    //TODO: Write your content to $dir (You'll need to provide this piece)
    //Release the lock
    flock($file, LOCK_UN);
}
else{
    die("Unable to acquire lock");
}
//Always close the file handle
fclose($file);
```

Comment: And if i use a datebase for it, that datebase can also store images? And how can i do this ? Like:

First user:
1 - name - consultant id - image
2 - name - consultant id - image
3 - name - consultant id - image 
and  so on

Comment: anyway there will be 200+ images so i think this is a bad idea

Comment: A database can store any type of data, including images. You can easily store the image in a BLOB datatype in most traditional SQL databases.

Comment: The ideal storage format depends on how you are going to consume the data. Once uploaded, how do you intend to use it?

Comment: So when my friend draws the winner to do it like this:
She looks at the last folder ( ok, the last folder is 355 ), she put 355 number in random.org and randomize one number between 1 - 355. Let's say the winner is number 20, she looks in folder "number 20" looks at the image (if is valid registration or not) , and in txt for contact information (id consultant is enough)

Comment: Alright, so it sounds like it will be a manual process and at a fairly small scale. I understand what you're trying to do now. I'll update my answer with a more complete example.